# Python JSON Dictionary List Conversion

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

In the code below it creates a dictionary where some values are lists. I am trying to retain the list but when it update the dictionary it turns the value into a string.

```py
json_file = open(json_path+json_template_file)
data = load(json_file)

any_char = "[!-\/:-@[-{-~a-zA-Z]*[!-\/:-@[-{-~a-zA-Z0-9]*'"

for key in data:
    match key:
        case 'name':
            a = 1
        case 'tasks':
            task_input_str = str(data[key])            
            # task_key
            task_key_re = re.sub("'task_key':\s'"+ any_char + "*'","'task_key': '"+ task_key + "'",task_input_str)
            data.update(task_key_re)
```

I wish to update the dictionary with the original list as per when the JSON is imported.

Comment: It will be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve if you give some sample input and desired output.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that '**task_key_re**' is a string, not a dictionary.

And updating a dictionary using the `update()` method expects another dictionary as input, not a string.

To retain the list value, you should modify the dictionary directly instead of converting it to a string and then trying to update it.

Your Code will be:

```
json_file = open(json_path + json_template_file)
data = load(json_file)

any_char = "[!-\/:-@[-{-~a-zA-Z]*[!-\/:-@[-{-~a-zA-Z0-9]*'"

for key in data:
    match key:
        case 'name':
            a = 1
        case 'tasks':
            task = data[key] 
            task['task_key'] = task_key  #Update the 'task_key' within the list
```

I this code ,the '**task_key**' value is modified directly within the '**tasks**' list.

(Make sure that **'task_key'** is defined before this code snippet and contains the desired value to be assigned to the '**task_key**' key within the list).

Comment: The thing is that the TASK variable is a list with only one element containing the information. It is not a list within a list.

Comment: BEFORE 'tasks': [{'task_key': AFTER 'tasks': "[{'task_key':  - This is the issue.